# How Pass String Parameter in ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, actionlink, html.actionlink

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know how I can pass string into `ActionLink()` at following snippet? As you can see I am passing `, new { id = i.Id}` but I need to pass the name of the files as string into URL

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
....
<ul class="list-group">
    @foreach (var i in Model)
    {
        <li class="list-group-item">
            @Html.ActionLink(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(i).Substring(0, 5), "Map", new { id = i.Id })
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to pass the file name with the file extension (that will cause an exception because of the dot unless you modify other code depending on your routes)?

Comment: no I am willing to only pass the name of the file and that's why I used the `Substring()` to get rid of the extention

Comment: `new { id = i }` is all you need (assuming your method is `Map(string id)`